# Chopped a lemon then rubbed my cat, am worried

Tags: cats, safety

I basically need someone to talk some sense into me. I chopped half a lemon, wiped my hands and then about five minutes later rubbed my cat's stomach. He was just grooming his stomach there.

Could he have ingested enough lemon to get sick through my hand touching his fur and then him licking his fur? I realise the answer is probably no but I've tried myself in knots.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, mate, I think your cat will be fine. You said you chopped half a lemon, so I assume  you were holding the peel part of the lemon? Although as you chop the lemon, the rind that's being cut would produce oil (I think), there probably won't be much on your hand (the other hand I assume is holding the knife, so would be 'clean'). AND you said you wiped your hands. So I really think your cat will be fine.

If you said that you just squeezed the lemon (where the toxic chemicals e.g. linalool and limonene would come out in large quantities) then I would be a bit concerned.

relax and play with your kitty!

Comment: the thing is,only the peel is toxic for cats the linked Q&A explains it well.

Comment: @trondhansen, yes I get that, but I assume that the op's hand just hold the lemon to be cut, not squeezing the peel (where linalool and limonene would be expressed in large amounts.